# AWS S3 bucket policy with HTTP Referer gives 403 always

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to add bucket-policy into my S3 bucket. I have a requirement that only my website should be able to access the resources from the bucket. I found that HTTP Referer is useful in the current scenario, hence I have gone through the following steps:

1. Created the bucket
2. Uploaded a png file into it
3. Disabled *Block all public access*
4. Added below bucket policy

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1599658083694",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Sid": "Stmt1599658081534",
          "Action": [
              "s3:GetObject"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mywebsiteso/*",
          "Condition": {
              "StringLike": {
                  "aws:Referer": "https://blue.mywebsite.io/*"
              }
          },
          "Principal": "*"
      }
  ]
}
```

I'm now assuming that it should be accessible from my website, and not directly using an URL. Here are the result of both

Using Direct URL
[image]

5. I have created an HTML page (test.html) with the below content and added to the website root directory.

```
<a href="https://mywebsiteso.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/403.PNG">click here</a>
```

[image]

However, when I click on the link, it showing the same response of 403.

I have tried several ways like:

```
 "aws:Referer": [
                 "http://blue.mywebsite.io",
                 "http://blue.mywebsite.io/*",
                 "http://www.blue.mywebsite.io/*",
                 "https://blue.mywebsite.io",
                 "https://blue.mywebsite.io/*",
                 "https://www.blue.mywebsite.io/*"
                ]
```

Comment: Just check this whether you follow all this steps https://help.optimizepress.com/article/656-setup-your-amazon-s3-bucket-permissions-to-protect-videos-you-use-in-the-video-player-element

Comment: Thanks for the link @aviboy2006!, I have some doubt here, is this (bucket policy with HTTP Referer) work only for attachment files?

Comment: It’s should work for others also.

Comment: Can you enable [s3 access logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html). One of the values logged is [Referer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html). This way you can inspect the value of the referer.

Comment: Also how did you setup ssl? Are you going through CloudFront? Its not stated in your question.

Comment: Also make sure in Chrome Development Tools on the Network tab that the browser is actually sending the referer header. There have been [some recent security related changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default) as to when it's sent.

Comment: @Marcin  *Also how did you setup ssl?* The web server is on-premise, and not using CloudFront there. I will check the logs and update the question..

Comment: Blocking all public access has to be OFF I think. I am not sure why you would do this, but please do not do it for security, referrers are trivial to spoof. If you'd like a CDN you might want to look into AWS CloudFront.

Comment: @gergelykalman: I have mentioned in the question if that's missed *Disabled Block all public access* I have specific use case where web app is accessing document images from S3, And I want to prevent user to access that path directly from a browser. I'm new to AWS, so it might me wrong choice!

Comment: @DivyangDesai The user by definition will be able to access these from a browser, since they have to see the image. Any tech savvy user can spoof the referrer header and access the image circumventing your website.

Comment: Independently of the fact that whether public access to your bucket is allowed or not (as indicated by @gergelykalman, it shouldn't), please, be aware that the ```aws:referer``` condition should not be used to restrict unauthorized access, but when you do not want that other sites use your content. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html. If you want to restrict the access to your bucket to a certain application, you can establish an ```IpAddress``` operator over an ```aws:SourceIp``` condition equal to the IP or IP range of your application

Comment: I suggest following @Marcin suggestion to enable s3 access logs in your bucket. Once that is done, you can click on your link in your site. Then go check the value logged for `Referer` in the logs. Once you get that value, plug that into the `aws:Referer` condition in the bucket policy and see if that works.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the page with different browsers or curl command? Some browsers and extensions might drop referer header by default. Also it might depend on browser settings. I confirm that Brave browser drop the referer header.